# Requirements for microcontroller programming of an RFID project

Tags: microcontroller, programming, microprocessor

I am new to microelectronic.But I have a little knowledge in some hobby circuits etc.

I want to make a fully automated circuit for my vehicle,by using a short range RFID sensor for detecting the unique person(Driver) for driving a vehicle,-So as to avoid anyone driving my vehicle..

My idea is..

[image: bike project details]

**program description**

- When the owner sit on his vehicle and put the **key on** vehicle.
- RFID sensor start detecting necessary tags.
- If necessary tag found detected, vehicle will turn on
- If no necessary tags found,inform the owner with some voice alert

**Advantage is that**

no one can ride our bike without necessary RFID tag(Because No one knows about our personal RFID tag).

This is the first step.

**Is it possible to create a micro-controller program using high-level programs like JAVA or VB etc and convert to hexadecimal codes,for my MC??.**

Thanks in advance..

Comment: No... Rather not advised to use so.... Prefer C for programming on Microcontroller or you can use Arduino or raspberry pi which comes with lot of libraries and easy if you don't know much about Embedded programming

Comment: @Swanand, I am also a programmer,But I don't know much about embeded C.

Comment: That's why I suggested Arduino or raspberry pi

Answer (score 1):

I regard this as a too serious project for a beginner, since you're meddling with something that needs reliable operation - with little experience you might leave critical bugs in your code which would leave you with a mild annoyance at best or a damaged vehicle at worst.

To answer your original question:

You could program it in a high level language, however that would defeat the purpose of a microcontroller, because you'd be using it's resources very wastefully. If you really want a high level language, you can just plop a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), or a [Carambola2](http://www.8devices.com/carambola-2) unit in there.

If you desperately want to go for a high level language, you could go for an [Espruino](http://www.espruino.com/), however javascript is quite similar to C/C++, so why not just go for the true way of coding microcontrollers immediately?

I'd recommend trying an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/), since it'd have all the modules you'd need easily available as well as a rich array of drivers/libraries already written for said modules. This would mean that you would have to study the C language a bit, however it's nothing too difficult if you need just a simple application to recognise a specific hex stream from an RFID reader and switch output pins accordingly.

Comment: ,Thanks for your kind reply. I completed Diploma in computer eng:-obviously I know programs like C,C++,java,java script like that.But I don't know much about embedded C.Please give me a sample program with example.

Comment: Here's a simple Arduino based example: http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/PRFID
And here's a more serious write-up with code which doesn't rely on the Arduino libraries: https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ee476/FinalProjects/s2006/cjr37/Website/index.htm